# Xcode to show actual device on simulation?

Tags: xcode

I know its being asked but i could not find an answer.
For promotional video, we need to see the simulation inside an `iPhone` .
When running the `iPhone6` simulation -you don't see the device .

Is there a way to simulate this with a device

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do that with `Xcode`. There is another way to show an app movie inside an iPhone.
Record a video of the app using `QuickTime` (screen live recording option) with your actual `iPhone` connected. Then, take that into `iMovie`, set an iPhone image as a background (just drag it to there), put the recorded movie on top of that image, and chose "picture in picture" from the menu, and just position the movie right on top of the iPhone image.

This way, only using a `mac` free softwares, you can record app usage and show it inside an `Apple` devices.